# Pandas Dataframe Flatten values to cell based on column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, flatten

I have a simple data frame that I am reading in from Excel. To process further, I need to combine the "store" values into a list in one cell that corresponds to the given zone. To clarify, I want to have only one row per zone. In the corresponding "store" column will be a list of all the corresponding stores in one cell.

Current State

[image: current state]

Desired State
[image: Desired State]

I have tried to implement melt with no success.

```
store_df  = pd.read_excel("Zones_by_Store.xlsx")
store_df.groupby(store_df['Price Zone Name'])
pd.melt(store_df, id_vars=['Price Zone Name'], value_vars=['Store No'])
store_df.to_csv('Stores.csv')
```

Comment: There are multiple zones after the one shown, the pictures were truncated for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

price_zone = ['CA2', 'CA2', 'CA2']
store_num = [112, 162, 726]
df = pd.DataFrame(price_zone, columns=['Price Zone'])
df['Store No'] = store_num

df = (df.groupby(['Price Zone']).agg({'Store No': lambda x: x.tolist()}).reset_index())

print(df)
```

Comment: please accept and upvote this answer if it helped